# Firefox drag-n-drop not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, firefox, uploader

Firefox drag-n-drop for pictures didn't work: it drops the picture, but didn't put the appropriate code in post.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click the image button
2. Drag an image to the image dialog box.
3. Click confirm.
4. See the 'uploading' indicator appear.

Then the dialog box disappears and all we are left with is the grey overlay, no image uploaded. Clicking on the page dismisses the overlay, but no image is added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Already fixed and in the next build.

This was also affecting drag-n-drop on Opera.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed. I tried to prove you wrong, by posting a picture of the toolbar button and process, but on Firefox 20 *the drag-n-drop upload **doesn't work***.

To make your bug report more complete, steps to reproduce:

1. Click the image button
2. Drag an image to the image dialog box.
3. Click confirm.
4. See the 'uploading' indicator appear.

Then the dialog box disappears and all we are left with is the grey overlay, no image uploaded. Clicking on the page dismisses the overlay, but no image is added.

Comment: Shouldn't this be edited into the question?

Comment: @hims056: no, that would be an invalid edit.

Comment: @0A0D: I already edited the steps into the OP.